# How to hide web.config from directory browsing?

Tags: iis

I use IIS8 and I'm trying to hide web.config from the files list on my site but I just can't seem to find a solution for that. Can you help me please? :)

Comment: web.config should be automatically hidden as per IIS security rules. You shouldn't be able to browse to it.

Comment: I can't browse to it, but it is being shown in the files list and I want to hide it.. Is it possible?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Right click the file and mark it as hidden. It will stop showing up in IIS directory browsing.

Comment: This may cause IIS to fail with 500 server errors (500.19, substatus 5).  At least, it did for me...

Comment: If you have the value set to "False" in a variable "Allow Hidden Files to be Listed" in "WebDAV Settings" 

Comment: Unfortunately IIS resets the hidden flag every time it's updated, so this isn't permanent

Answer (score 3):

Use the command prompt for each web.config file

`attrib +H web.config`

You can also do a Find with Windows Explorer and search for "web.config" in the directory where you store all of your web data, then right-click on each one there to enable the Hidden flag as well. With the Find GUI > View options - you can hide already hidden files so you know which ones you've already changed.

Comment: This may cause IIS to fail with 500 server errors (500.19, substatus 5).  At least, it did for me...

Comment: Unfortunately IIS resets the hidden flag every time it's updated, so this isn't permanent

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by

1. moving all of the configuration options from the browsable directory's `web.config` file into a new `location` element in the site-wide `web.config` file
2. deleting `web.config` from the browsable directory so it would neither appear in the directory listing nor be served by IIS

### Before

#### `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysubdirectory\web.config`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

`/mysubdirectory/web.config` appears in directory listings and is served.

### After

#### `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <!-- other existing site-wide settings -->
    </system.webServer>

    <!-- moved from C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysubdirectory\web.config -->
    <location path="mysubdirectory">
        <system.webServer>
            <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

#### `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysubdirectory\web.config`

Deleted

Now I can still list the other files in `mysubdirectory`, but `web.config` is no longer one of them. IIS also correctly returns a 404 if you try to navigate to `/mysubdirectory/web.config`.